# Pyspark structured streaming: issue unable to serialize object

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

I'm not understanding why my code raise an error.

Here's what I'm doing:

```
        streaming_query = (
            df.writeStream.option(
                "checkpointLocation",
                f'{config["checkpoint_location"]}/{rule["module_name"]}',
            )
            .foreachBatch(ProcessActions(config, rule, logger, session=spark_session).process)
            .trigger(processingTime="0 seconds")
            .queryName(rule["module_name"])
            .start()
        )
```

```
def process(self, df: pyspark.sql.DataFrame, _: int) -> None:

        if df.isEmpty():
            return

        df.foreachPartition(self.process_rows)
```

But whenever `df.foreachPartition` is called, I get the error :
`_pickle.PicklingError: Could not serialize object: TypeError: cannot pickle '_thread.lock' object`

I was using `df.collect()` instead of `df.foreachPartition`, but I noticed it is not a best practice because it limits the parallelism as it demand work to a single node driver.
My code before was like this:

```
def process(self, df: pyspark.sql.DataFrame, _: int) -> None:

        if df.isEmpty():
            return

        rows = df.collect()
        self.process_rows(rows)
```

I tried removing every argument passed to the `ProcessAction()`  in the  `foreachBatch()`, but it breaks the same way. I have also tried to pass a function to the `foreachBatch()` instead of a class and its method but the result is the same. I face this problem also using `df.foreach` instead of `df.foreachPartition`